# Is this a observation or a experiment? And does x affect x or y affect x?

Tags: probability, statistics

A study measures the mathematical knowledge among students who go to a school where the noise level is high and in one where the noise level is low. Assume that variable X = 'mathematics knowledge' and variable Y = 'school. Which scenario corresponds to this?

I feel like the answer is Observation study where Y affects X. because we are observing the world as it is and not experimenting with it. And we are not attempt to influence them, and we can not determine causation ( only correlation). is this correct way of thinking?

None of the above

Observation study where X affects Y.

Experimental study where Y affects X.

**Observation study where Y affects X.**

Experimental study where X affects Y

Comment: My **blind instinct**, which could easily be mistaken, is that *Experimental* is supposed to refer to having a noisy school, with few math students/knowledge, **then** implementing a **quiet - no noise** policy at this **particular** school, and then observing that the number of math students/knowledge at this particular school increases.  Excluding the option of "Observation study where X affects Y" seems trickier to me:  this exclusion seems based on the idea that math students **do not cause** non-math students to be quiet.

Comment: Food for thought:  I was taught that the statement (P unless Q) is equivalent to the statement (Q unless P).  Let P denote "I will go to the store" and Q denote "it is raining".  Compare the supposedly equivalent statements.  Does going to the store affect cloud formations?

Comment: Not a controlled study; observational. Noise may affect math knowledge; we hope to see if there is an association. It is hard to imagine that math knowledge would cause noise, unless some very unusual methods of teaching math are contemplated. '' // This would have been a more appropriate question for our site if you had ventured some views of your own.

Answer (score 1):

Your thinking is correct. There are two questions here we have to work through:

1. Does $X$ affect $Y$ or does $Y$ affect $X$?
2. Is this study an experiment or is it observational?

First, on the direction of the effect. The study wants to determine the relationship between the noise level in the school ($Y$) and the mathematics knowledge of the students ($X$). Either we have a study that wants to know whether the mathematics knowledge of the students affects how noisy the school is ($X$ affects $Y$), or we have a study that asks whether students at a noisier/quieter school perform better in mathematics ($Y$ affects $X$). Although both are plausible, the latter is much more likely the question the study is trying to answer, so we'll go with $Y$ affects $X$.

Then, we want to know if it's observational or experimental. An experiment is typically denoted through some aspect of randomness in the independent variable, which is $Y$ (school noisiness) in this case. We have two schools, where one is noisy and the other is quiet. We didn't randomly assign one school to the noisy condition and one to the quiet condition. There may be something else (a confounding variable) that affects both how noisy the school is and how well the students perform in math, like the behavior of the students, the rules in place at the school, etc. So, in this case, we have an observational study, where we simply observe that there is a difference in mathematics performance that's correlated with the noise levels at the school. That's why this type of study can only measure correlation, and not causation.

Comment: Nice explanation